# How convert the things before <br> to text?

Tags: xpath, lxml

I'd like to use `lxml` to convert the thing before `<br>` of an element to string. Supposed the following `p` element is retrieved by `xpath()`, could anybody show me the comment to convert the thing before `<br>` to text (`xxx yyy` in this case)?

```
<p><span><strong>xxx</strong></span> <strong>yyy</strong><br> <span><img alt="" class="content-image content-image-right" src="yyy.jpg"></span>zzz</p>
```

Comment: This is not valid XML: `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 1 and span, line 1, column 144`. The `img` element is not closed.

Comment: It was truncated when I made the example. You can suppose that there is an closing img.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the children of the `p` element and collect the recursive text content of each until the `br` element is reached.

```
from lxml import etree

p = etree.fromstring("""<p><span><strong>xxx</strong></span> <strong>yyy</strong><br/> <span><img alt="" class="content-image content-image-right" src="yyy.jpg"/></span>zzz</p> """)

text = []
for child in p.getchildren():
    text.append(etree.tostring(child, method="text"))
    if child.tag == "br":
        break

print(b"".join(text))
```

Output:

```
b'xxx yyy '
```